# How generators can work inside event loops like pyinput

Tags: python-3.x, events, keyboard, generator, coroutine

For example, this code is not working:

```
from pynput import keyboard 


def on_press(key):
   global play
    
   if str(key) == "'x'":
     play = 'Play'

play = ''

with keyboard.Listener(on_press = on_press, suppress=True) as listener:         

  while listener.is_alive(): # infinite loop which runs all time   

    def pump():
      num = 0
      while True:
        yield num # generator
        num += 1   

    if play == 'Play':
        next(gen)

  listener.join()
```

No matter how I put the generator function or using a global variable, I always have a `StopIteration:` error or others.

I want to control the generator, so I can "play" and "pause" with keyboard keys.

While this code works:

```
def pump():
  num = 0
  while True:
     yield num
      num += 1

gen = pump()
next(gen)  #play
next(gen)
```

I'm so bewildered...

Comment: What makes you think it's not working? When you set `play` to `"Play"` it will continuously call the generator since there is nothing changing `play` back from `"Play"`. Also continuously defining `pump` within your loop means every time you call it `num` will be set back to `0`.

Comment: If that doesn't clear it up, I can explain in more detail in an answer.

Comment: Yes exactly, @Axe319, I've tried to put `pump` outside the event loop but it's unrecognized. Other combination also to put `gen = pump()` either in the main or inside `on_press`. I'm using jupyter notebook, could be causing it since it has own loop? I'm itch to control generator with buttons to let them 'play', 'pause' (suspend), then you can continue where you left off with 'play' again, then finally 'stop'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Jupyter notebooks but I tried the VS Code extension and it seems to work in them as well.

Here is some sample code to prove the generator is working.

```
from pynput import keyboard
import sys
def on_press(key):
    global play
    if str(key) == "'x'":
        play = 'Play'
    # added to provide a way of escaping the while loop
    elif str(key) == "'q'":
        sys.exit(1)

def pump():
    num = 0
    while True:
        # added as proof your generator is working
        print(num)
        yield num
        num += 1

gen = pump()
play = ''
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, suppress=True) as listener:
    while listener.is_alive():
        if play == 'Play':
            next(gen)
    listener.join()
```

This will infinitely call `next(gen)` since there is no way to unset `play` from `"Play"` in the code. Once it's set, it will continue infinitely looping and `if play == 'Play':` will always be `True`.

Now, onto your example.
This line:

```
next(gen)
```

will error.

`gen` is never defined in your code.
I assume this was just a typo and you have `gen = pump()` somewhere.

Additionally, defining `pump` in your loop will almost certainly have unintended consequences.

Suppose you do have `gen = pump()` immediately after the definition.
`play` will be set to `"Play"` when you press the `x` key. You will continuously call `next(gen)`.
However, this time after each loop `pump` will be redefined and `num` will be set to `0`. It will `yield` the `0` and continue to do so infinitely.

So what did you mean to do?
Probably something like this:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import sys
def on_press(key):
    global play
    if str(key) == "'x'":
        play = 'Play'
    elif str(key) == "'q'":
        sys.exit(1)

def pump():
    global play
    num = 0
    while True:
        play = ''
        print(num)
        yield num
        num += 1
gen = pump()
play = ''
with keyboard.Listener(on_press = on_press, suppress=True) as listener:
    while listener.is_alive():
        if play == 'Play':
            next(gen)
    listener.join()
```

Personally, I would avoid the use of globals.
However this, calls the `next(gen)` once with the `x` key press. The generator sets `play` back to `""` avoiding subsequent calls of `next(gen)` until `x` is pressed again.

Comment: Thank you. I intend to create a "play" button to let the generator run, keep adding numbers (I'd add a `time.sleep()`), then "pause" to stop it at the current number so you can resume with another "play" or "stop" to reset it back to 0. Your code gives me an idea. I can use something like `send()` to resume from pause.